# Installing a spark cluster on a hadoop cluster

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to install an apache spark cluster on a hadoop cluster.

I am looking for best pracises in this regard. I am assuming that the spark master needs to be installed on the same machine as the hadoop namenode and the spark slaves on the hadoop datanodes. Also, where all do I need to install scala? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If your Hadoop cluster is running YARN just use yarn mode for submitting your applications. That's going to be the easiest method without requiring you to install anything beyond simply downloading the Apache Spark distribution to a client machine. One additional thing you can do is deploy the Spark assembly to HDFS so that you can use the spark.yarn.jar config when you call spark-submit so that the JAR is cached on the nodes.

See here for all the details: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html

Comment: Sounds good, I untarred the latest spark binary distribution, and ran this command /opt/spark-1.6.1/sbin/start-all.sh, but am getting an error:

Comment: Failed to find Spark assembly in /opt/spark-1.6.1/assembly/target/scala-2.10.
test205:   You need to build Spark before running this program.

Comment: I am getting now: test205: failed to launch org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker:   on the slave logfile shows:[hadoop@test205 ~]$ tail -f /opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-without-hadoop/logs/spark-hadoop-org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker-1-test205.kartikv.com.out
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger

Comment: If you're using yarn then you don't need to run start-all.sh, you simple set your YARN_CONF_DIR and HADOOP_CONF_DIR then set your master to yarn. Please read the yarn deployment link I posted earlier.